LaTeX not rendering in RMarkdown after update
As a non-speaker of LaTeX, I frequently use RStudio's markdown editor to do what little LaTeX-y things I need to. One of these things was my CV, for which I used this template. Much to my dismay, since the last time I rendered it, something has changed 'under the hood.' Now the LaTeX isn't rendering -- it's just being reproduced as text:

To reproduce the error yourself, you can download the markdown file and the tex template.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even being able to precisely describe the error would be nice. I've already tried two LLMs and searching through previous SO posts.

Yes, I appreciate the pointer, but I've seen that the occasionally don't like people who work in (R)markdown. I might end up going over there in the end, though

Try adding format = "latex" to your CV_table() definition:
CV_table <- function(x){
  knitr::kable(x, format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, col.names = NULL, escape= FALSE, linesep = "\\addlinespace") %>% 
  column_spec(1,"2.5cm", bold = TRUE) %>% 
  column_spec(2, "13.3cm")}


